# Neptune with gremlin error when creating edge

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I'm new neptune and graph dbs and trying to create a simple edge between two vertexs and getting a weird error that I don't fully understand.

```
const user = await g.V().has('name', 'john').next()
const group = await g.addV("group").property("name", 'johns created group').next()
 const edge = await g.V(user).addE('memberOf').to(g.V(group)).next(); // this line causes error
```

The third line causes me to get the following error

```
Error: The child traversal of ... was not spawned anonymously - use the __ class rather than a TraversalSource to construct the child traversal
```

Any thoughts on what is going on or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After TinkerPop 3.5.0, you can no longer spawn a child traversal from `g`. It must be spawned anonymously from `__` therefore:

```
g.V(user).addE('memberOf').to(__.V(group))
```

More information can be found in the [Upgrade Documentation](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.5.1/upgrade/#_anonymous_child_traversals) for 3.5.0.

Comment: where/how can one access this `__` variable? It appears to not be exported by the `gremlin` package in nodejs. Any ideas?

Comment: please see Common Imports here: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-javascript-imports

Comment: You can import `__` with `from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __`.